# Algorithm to search substring in a circular string?

Tags: algorithms, search-algorithms, strings, substrings

I need an algorithm to search for substrings. I checked different resources, and it seems that the most known algorithms are the [Boyer–Moore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm) and the [Knuth–Morris–Pratt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm).

However, as far as I understand, these operate on "regular" strings, but what I need is a substring search on a **circular string**.

A circular string as a string characterized only by its size and the order of the elements, i.e. `ABCD` is the same as `BCDA`, `CDAB` and `DABC`

An source/query example that should succeed:

```
Source string: EFxxxABCxxxxxD
Query string:  DEF
```

Do you know of any references on substring search on circular strings? Any advice on how to do this?

(Possibly) related:

- CS: [Automaton for substring matching](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/13009/)
- SO: [main differences between the KMP and BM algorithms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12656160/)
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm

Comment: Do you have more details about the problem? Can the circular string contain less elements than the substring pattern? Do you use the same pattern repeatedly so that it might be worth compiling it (as in Boyer-Moore or KMP)?

Comment: @babou Q1: no, Q2: I don't understand, what do you mean by `it might be worth compiling it` ? At present, I implemented what @Marc-Johnston suggested, seams to work but I haven't done extensive tests by now.

Comment: I guess my question may not be properly stated. If you consider the
KMP algorithm, there is a cost in building the table, which is O(m), m
being the query string size. If the same query string is used many
times, then this cost may be ignored as it is amortized on many
queries. In that case, considering the cost on concatenating small
loops makes sense in assessing complexity. But if you include the
table creation in the cost, then the discussion on concatenation cost
is pretty much pointless. I am working on how to avoid most of the
concatenation, hence the question.

Comment: When you reply "Q1: no", you mean that the source string is always larger than the query string? right?

Comment: `you mean that the source string is always larger than the query string`: yes.

Comment: @babou On previous comment, I see what you mean. At present, my concerns are more on other parts of the "global" algorithm on which I'm working on (this is only a"sub"-problem) than on optimizing. And I have rather small strings (~10^2) and query string will be small too ( 1-10). But maybe consider posting an answer ?

Comment: I did post an answer, but removed it as there is a subtle graph problem I have to solve better (my solution was not correct because of missing cases). But it concerns only the case when the query is larger than the source.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create a temporary source string by concatenating itself together until the length of the source string is at least twice the length of the search string.  The source string must be concatenated at least once.

Then perform a simple (non-circular) search on that temporary string.

Comment: If the source string is of length $n$ and the query string of length $m$, then this algorithm is $O(n + m)$ if KMP is run on the resulting instance, which is the same complexity as KMP on a noncircular string, which is optimal. Though you should duplicate the string until it has at least $n + m - 1$ characters, as @keb's example shows.

Comment: Agreed ... this algorithm is pretty much O(n + m) ... although a binary search tree may be able to make it O(log n + m)

Comment: I updated the algorithm to denote a minimum of 1 concatenation is required.

Comment: Also note this ... the circular problem is really solved only with the concatenation step.  Then the problem becomes an algorithm for substring searching.  To truly improve the big O for the original problem, the concatenation algorithm needs to be improved, not the substring search.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "improve the concatenation algorithm" ? To me, concatenate is not an algorithm but an operation ("AB" + "CD" = "ABCD"). Or maybe you suggest that a partial contatenation can be enough ?

Comment: I thought about it a little bit... And really the source string only has to be n + m - 1 in length ... doubling the source string in length each time would be wasteful... n+m-1 would be the least amount of characters ... which reduces the search string length

Comment: Another optimization might be... Instead of performing concatenation... implement the substring search manually and do a (mod)ular loop of n+m-1 characters on the source string... depending on how thats implemented it may or may not be faster because built-in substring searches are usually highly optimized

Comment: It can be done without concatenation, using an optimized substring search algorithm. This makes the complexity dependent only on the size of the source string, i.e. just $O(n)$  assuming preprocessing of the query string.  cc @BryceSandlund

Comment: Accepting, with a warning for the future reader: read the comments, some more optimization possible. Or maybe you could edit your answer ?

Comment: @babou "assuming prepocessing of the query string" <- this takes $O(m)$ time. I assume you are referring to KMP.

Comment: @BryceSandlund Yes, KMP. But there is that discussion on whether one must increase the source string to the size of the pattern, when the pattern is longer. From a complexity view point, worrying about this makes sense only if you abstract away the $O(m)$ preprocessing, by considering it is amortized over many searches. This lead me to a problem I do not know how to solve ... but it could be a nice question.